# Can't send mail using apache commons mail when smtp appender for log4j is configured

Tags: java, email, log4j2, apache-commons

I have a working code that creates and sends an `org.​apache.​commons.​mail.HtmlEmail` (version 1.5), but that same code doesn't word when I have SMTPAppender configured for log4j2 (version 2.1), if I remove the SMTPAppender, my code runs again. This is the log from when SMTPAppender is configured and my code fails:

```
Loading javamail.default.providers from jar:file:/home/stirr/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.6/javax.mail-1.5.6.jar!/META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imap, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imaps, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtp, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtps, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3s, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: getProvider() returning provider protocol=smtps; type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@240a1e4d; class=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport; vendor=Oracle
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 465, isSSL true
mai. 09, 2022 10:36:01 AM nfce.receita.nfe.envio.SendEmail sendXMLsAndReports
SEVERE: null
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Pay attention where it says:

> "trying to connect to host **"localhost"**, port 465, isSSL true"

When I remove SMTPAppender, this message change and try to connecto to the correct host:

> "trying to connect to host **"smtp.gmail.com"**, port 465, isSSL
> false"

**EDIT 1:**

This is the relevant part of my log4j2.xml and the class that sends my email:

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <SMTP name="Mail" subject="My Subject" 
              to="mydestination@gmail.com" 
              from="myorigin@gmail.com"
              smtpUsername="myorigin@gmail.com" smtpPassword="mypasswd"
              smtpHost="smtp.gmail.com" smtpPort="465" bufferSize="50"
              smtpProtocol="smtps" smtpDebug="true">
        </SMTP>
        
        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="Mail"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    
    <Loggers>    
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

ps: I omitted console appender and file appender to focus on smtp appender configuration

```
org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com"); 
email.setAuthentication("myorigin@gmail.com", "mypasswd");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
email.setFrom("myorigin@gmail.com", "ERROR SISEMAIL");
email.addTo("mydestination@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("My Subject");
email.setHtmlMsg("My message");
email.setCharset("UTF-8");
email.setDebug(true);

if (attachs != null) {
    for (File attach : attachs) {
         if (attach != null) {
            EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
            attachment.setPath(attach.getAbsolutePath());
            attachment.setName(attach.getName());
            attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
            email.attach(attachment);
        }
    }
} 

email.send();
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have made a project that illustrate the error: https://github.com/lleandroo93/sof-q72173964

The problem seems to be related to one local lib that I have no control and is essential to the project (cannot be replaced or removed), please follow the steps described in the README of the project

Comment: Please share your code (or at least the relevant part).

Comment: Which version of Log4j2 are you using? How do you configure the `SMTPAppender` and `HtmlEmail`? Both can use Java system properties `mail.*`, which would explain the interference.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz log4j-1.2-api version 2.1. I'm debuging through commons.mail and probably is something about system properties, something inside javax.mail.Session is overriding my propertie

Comment: @LeandroCavalcante: please upgrade to version `2.17.2` of Log4j2. Version 2.1 is 8 years old and has many security vulnerabilities, including the famous Log4Shell.

Comment: @ewramner please see my edit 2 to access the project to reproduce the error

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks for the information to upgrade, I have made this and created a project to reproduce the error, please see my edit 2

Comment: The problematic lib is a shaded jar that has packed several other libraries into itself, including Java mail. Perhaps you can remove some of those files from the jar (as much as possible that you don't need) and see if it helps? Even if you don't control the original you may get away with stripping out things from it before you use it.

Comment: @ewramner I opened the jar and removed jaxax/mail folder and it worked